# css: how get border around image?

Tags: html, css

I have a background image but cannot get the red border around it. This is my html:

```
<div id="parentDiv" class="bg">
  <div class="row childDiv ">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQHvElQPvE4mpefl9D6qy2BmBsD2UCbKdJbn2I1kkpFRaTDoLhb2g" alt="" /></div>
    <div class="col-md-6">two</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the css:

```
#parentDiv {
    position: relative;
    border:3px solid red;
    padding:10px;
    /*width:100%;*/
    height:400px;
}


#parentDiv .childDiv {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width:100%;
    border: 2px solid green;
    margin:5px;
}

/*todo responsive image style */
.bg
{
    background-image:url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?w=940&h=650&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:contain;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

How can I get the red border around the backgroundimage? Also  how to get the green border around the childdiv? [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NgxJWb)

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly, but I'm assuming you want the red border around the background image and the green border around the other image?  If so, see my solution.

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
#parentDiv.bg{
  border:10px solid red;
}
```

Your CSS has to be specified for class bg which is under parentDiv. You have given it to just bg. Add the above CSS.

You can have a look at the live example [here in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0y95w14x/1)

Answer (score 0):

Please check your answer in the fiddle

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zzrbvJ

```
#parentDiv {
    position: relative;
    border:3px solid red;
    padding:10px;
    height:400px;
}


#parentDiv .childDiv {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width:100%;
    margin:5px;
}

.img-responsive {
    border: 2px solid green;
}
```

Comment: the width of the image is not 940px anymore, would like to keep the ratio

Answer (score 0):

This way gives borders around both images.  If you want the green border around the second image, just add a class to your image (`<img class="img-responsive border"...`) and add the border properties in CSS.  You probably don't want to add the border properties to the `.img-responsive` class in case you use that in other places.

```css
.border {
  border: 2px solid green;
}

#parentDiv {
    position: relative;
    border:3px solid red;
    padding:10px;
    height:400px;

}


#parentDiv .childDiv {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width:100%;
    margin:5px;
}

.bg {
    background-image:url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?w=940&h=650&auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;

}
```

```html
<div id="parentDiv" class="bg">
  <div class="row childDiv ">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <img class="img-responsive border" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQHvElQPvE4mpefl9D6qy2BmBsD2UCbKdJbn2I1kkpFRaTDoLhb2g" alt="" /></div>
    <div class="col-md-6">two</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hi, another question : how can I keep the original width of the background image which is 940px? It is not responsive anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following at the end of your css codes:

```
.img-responsive {
     border: 1px solid red;
}
```